# How to maintain low latency when working with Personally identifiable information across country

Tags: architecture, database-design

The question is straight forward :

Personally identifiable information ( PII ) of an individual ( regardless of the persons citizenship) has to be on the countries server where an account is created due to compliance reason.

E.g: Your account information present on facebook, linkedin, paypal, global banks or Expedia has to reside on the country's servers where it was created ( or where you are residing).

However this information has to be accessible at low latency in an all the countries for varied use case :

1. individual (herself/himself )  is accessing the account outside the country .
2. the enterprise may need the user information for auditing/ shortlisting  or monitoring purpose.

How to achieve low latency in such case ?  Is it even possible.

Comment: Does "has to reside on server X" imply "and cannot be cached anywhere else"?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer would depend on the specific country and wording of their laws and which exactly information and how to you need to process. Basically, it would get into one the following categories:

- The government is fine with copying the PII abroad, only needs to have it accessible to own law enforcement (or, whatever kind of enforcement they have), or they only object massive copying of PII of all users abroad, but individual copying for legitimate purpose is allowed. In this case it is fine to make a cache in the destination.
- The PII should not be transferred abroad, but should be processed inside the country, so that only summarized data without the PII is copied abroad. So you do that. It would depend on the specific task you want to perform how exactly you do it.
- Whatever you want to do is not considered a legitimate operation for the PII and you simply should not be doing it (staying in the law boundaries).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than focusing on what you need to achieve, I'd suggest in focusing on what you can afford to relax on. Do you need to have low latency at all times on all regions? Can you afford a higher latency on the first login when someone accessed the data from a different country for the first time?

Individuals generally don't move countries very frequently, so you probably can migrate the primary copy of the user data between multiple regions to follow the user's last login location. This way data may take time to initially migrate if the user goes overseas, but it will be low latency for all requests after the initial migration.

How up to date the data needs to be for enterprise to do their auditing? Maybe it's ok if the data is few days old?